# text indent inside input box with percentage subtraction

Tags: html, css, input

is there a way to do a text indent inside an input box such that the text is halfway in the box but offset to the left by 20 pixels?

```
.my-input {
    text-indent: calc(50%-20px);
}
```

Getting an error

[image: text indent calculation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is that you forgot to separate the operation with spaces inside the calc() function.
Changing it into this made it work.

```
.my-input {
    text-indent: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```